# Is the Spanish word "jamón" cognate with the English word "ham"?

Tags: etimología, historia, comida, animales, inglés

In linguistics, **cognates** are words that have a common etymological origin. A cognate etymon need not be inherited directly from a proto-language; the etymon can be borrowed from some other language, in which evolution produces cognate forms.

Is the Spanish word *jamón* ("ham") cognate with the English word *ham*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite their conceptual and phonetic similarity, no - they come from distinct PIE roots. Their unrelatedness becomes more clear when we consider that the initial `/x ~ h/` pronunciation of the 'j' in Spanish only developed in the 17th-18th centuries, and before this *jamón* was pronounced `/ʃa'mon/` (and originally `/ʒa'mon/`).

---

- `PIE` **kónh₂m* (“leg”)

  - `Proto-Germanic` **hamō*, **hammō*, **hanmō*

    - `Old English` **hamm* (“inner or hind part of the knee, ham”)

      - `Mid. English` *hamme*

        - `English` *ham*

---

- `PIE` **kamp-* (“to bend; crooked”)

  - `Ancient Greek` κάμπη (*kámpē*)

    - `Late Latin` *gamba*

      - `Old French` *jambe, gambe* (“leg”)

        - `French` *jambon, gambon*

          - `Spanish` *jamón*
          - `English` *gammon*

---

Note however that the synonym *gammon* **is** cognate to *jamón* (both inherited from the French *jambon*).

Comment: Off-topic comment: I think saying gammon and ham are synonyms is a bit strong since there are definitely some use cases where one is right and the other wrong at least in the dialect of English spoken in south eastern England.

Comment: @mdewey true, I was using "synonym" in its [weak](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synonym) sense.

Answer (score 0):

The below book about the origin of English words suggests that it does come from Latin. The author states:

> The extent to which many Latin-English words have been unjointed from their original form, or *de-Latinized*, in coming to us through the French, Spanish, or other Romanic languages, is quite remarkable. Two or three examples must suffice. It is through the Sp. jamon (*j* being pronounced as *h*), Fr. jambon, that we get *ham* (Gm: hamme, provincial and obsolete) from the Latin gamba, a leg.
>
> - [*Modern philology: its discoveries, history and influence ...*](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/008619104), Benjamin W. Dwight. (c.1860)

See also [this page](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=iau.31858000366918;view=1up;seq=438) in the same book.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, though I am inclined to doubt the author's credibility on etymology, given that a few sentences later he claims *much* and *mucho* are cognates (seemingly implying *much* is a loanword via *mucho*), which [they are not](https://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/comments/3a4xr5/how_do_we_know_that_english_much_and_spanish/).